# Get events from Facebook group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm developing a website for an association. The website would show the Facebook events with the help of Facebook's open API.

I have managed to do this with the events of a Facebook page, but I'm running into problems with a group. With a page, I have used [this code](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/07/display-facebook-events-to-your-website.html) and it works fine. However, groups work a bit different because the group is not an event member.

```
$fql = "SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description 
        FROM event WHERE eid IN ( 
            SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 221167777906963) 
        ORDER BY start_time asc";
```

Any help on making the query to get the events of a certain group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, we can't use the `event_member` table with groups. It looks like not possible to get the events of a group with FQL.

Luckily, it works using the Graph API:

[`http://graph.facebook.com/221167777906963/events`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=221167777906963/events)